# i'm trying to display xml data in custom cell but it's working, and it display only one data

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, iphone-developer-program

[image: I upload image that it for show you that by using this code how it display content in uitablevirw]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://avweatherforecasts.com/services/iphoneservice.php"];    
        DaTa=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];    
        NSLog(@"data----%@",DaTa);
        Xmlpaeser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:DaTa];    
        Xmlpaeser.delegate=self;    
        [Xmlpaeser parse];
        [Xmlpaeser release];

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



 - (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
        array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        strcontent=nil;
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{   

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"start"])
        {        
            Dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];    
      }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

        strcontent=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];

        NSLog(@"Strcontent----%@",strcontent);
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{


            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"]){
                [Dict setObject:strcontent forKey:elementName];
            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"min"]){
                [Dict setObject:strcontent forKey:elementName];
            }
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"max"]){
                [Dict setObject:strcontent forKey:elementName];
            }
            if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"forecast"]
                ) {

                [Dict setObject:strcontent forKey:elementName];
               NSLog(@"dict--%@",[Dict description]);
            }          
            else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"start"]){            
                [array addObject:Dict];

                [Dict release];     
        }
    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

        NSLog(@"array--%@",[array description]);       

    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return [array count];

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *identifier=@"cell";

        custome_cell *Cell=(custome_cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (Cell==nil) {

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"custome_cell" owner:self options:nil];
            Cell = [nib objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }    
        Cell.city.text=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"city"];
        Cell.min.text=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"min"];
        Cell.max.text=[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"max"];
        Cell.forecast.text =[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"forecast"];

        return Cell;    
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        return 80;
    }
```

Comment: it's not displaying xml data in custom cell of uitabelview.it's very urjent

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. It's a pity you didn't actually detail what the problem really is or what you have tried to do to fix it.

Comment: can i post output of this code....???

Comment: i m saying that it is not Displaying all the xml data in uitableview..

Comment: you have to create label or Text view for showing your detail in tabel view. cell.text can be used only once in tableview

Comment: You should show what research effort you put into solving this so far so we don't have to start helping you from scratch. At least explain the issue that you have in detail so that we have some idea the symptoms you are having. Also, please stop capitalizing your instance variable names - it makes your code hard to hard as it's against Objective-C style guidelines.

Comment: @sudha:- I used 4 uilabel for showing data...

Comment: @carl veazey:--Ok..and sorry,,i m new at this place so i don't know all of this...

Comment: @NikunjSuthar I understand, that's why I let you know. Please read [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) you'll find it very helpful to get good answers. Then edit your question after you've read it to apply what it says.

Comment: thank x..@carl veazey, i will keep in my mind..and this type of mistake will not happen again..

Comment: hey i upload the image, in image it display only one city's content in row.actually i want to display all city and it's content in tableview.

Comment: you can use simple table view...

Comment: @sudha--no, same problem happen in simple table view

Comment: first check your array.. Does it contain all data?

Comment: hey guyzz,,help me out...i m stuck with this....

Comment: @NikunjSuthar check out my answer.. I updated it

Comment: yup in array only one record store instead of all record,that's why it show only one record..

Comment: because you use same string for different fields like... [Dict setObject:strcontent forKey:elementName];

Comment: @sudha:---then i have to declare different string for different field???

Comment: yes you have to declare different strings

Comment: @sudha==I tried it,,but not happen anything.:(

Comment: thank x for everyone ,i do it..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...May be it will help you...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;   
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      return [CommentsGetArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        //[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



        commentsTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 4, 190, 50)];
        commentsTextView.delegate = self;
        commentsTextView.tag = 101;
        commentsTextView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        [commentsTextView setScrollEnabled:YES];

        commentsTextView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        commentsTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];
        commentsTextView.textColor =[UIColor blackColor];
        commentsTextView.editable = NO;
        [cell addSubview:commentsTextView];



    }



     commentsTextView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    commentsTextView.text = [[CommentsGetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"comment"];


    return cell;

}
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    return 70;
}
```

you can use as a label instead of uitextView and you can create more text views or label to show your data but remember change their frames.

Comment: thank x and let me try...

Comment: thatnk x @sudha. it really works

Comment: @NikunjSuthar you can accept the answer yr and also can upvote to my answer.. :)